# A dialogue between... well, stuff!

Tags: riddle

So, I'm trying out yet *another* format for puzzles.

> A: Stop thinking so badly!
>   B: But A, I can't! No matter what, I'll always be not rational.
>   A: Well, I can help.
>   B: How can you help? You're not real!
>   A: I am real! I'm talking to you, and you're real, therefore I'm real.
>   B: That's not how it works.
>   A: What, B, now you're a philosopher?
>   B: Well, I *am* from the land of great philosophers.
>   A: Oh, B, you're not Greek!
>   B: Well, many consider me Greek.
>   A: But you were known all throughout the lands! The Greeks just made you famous.
>   B: And what about you, A? What nationality are you?
>   A: I think I'm Italian.
>   B: No, you're Greek. Like me. :)
>   A: Really?
>   B: Yeah, conceived in Ancient Greece.
>   A: My history is sketchy.
>   B: Because you're not real.
>   A: And you, B, are not rational. What's 1+1?
>   B: 3, obviously! Also, these days, computers don't understand you.
>   A: What do you mean?
>   B: I mean, computers need a full blown *object* to represent you, full of clunky Polish Notation functions! Me, I'm just several bytes.
>   A: How could you do that?
>   B: I'm simple. You're complex.
>   A: I'm not complex yet. If we join, then we're complex.
>   B: True. Well, bye!
>   A: Bye! I can't wait to see you up north at my home!
>   B: No, come west to mine.
>   A: We were already in your realm, now it's my turn to host. Bye!

Who's A and who's B?

Hint:

> Everything here is literal.

Comment: Semi-nitpicky: Real numbers and imaginary numbers are both complex. Anything of the form $a+b\mathrm{i}$ is complex, even if $a$ or $b$ is $0$ (or both!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like

> A is the symbol for imaginary number *i* and
>  B is the greek symbol pi

A

> - Not real = imaginary,
>  - First seen in Greece in the first century AD
>  - Not studied in earnest until 16th century in Italy.
>  - Computers need special structures for complex/imaginary numbers
>  - "Up north at my home": complex numbers can be represented on an X/Y plane, and the imaginary axis is usually the vertical axis.

B

> - Irrational
>  - Known everywhere and made famous by the Greeks, thus we use their letter
>  - Together with *i*, they make a complex number
>  - On a complex number plot, the real axis is usual the horizontal

Comment: Damnit. a few seconds too late D:

Comment: haha, I was rushing through my reasoning to get it posted

Comment: @PatG Same.. Was just reading the question and immediately thought about [this T-shirt text](http://www.comicalshirt.com/image/cache/data/products/1755/1755-main-1024x915.jpg).

Comment: You did it! YAY!!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I was thinking about the same thing. I really wanted to test out this dialogue format.

Comment: Always assigning credit to yourself, @You hahaha